# How to have a quartet of values using replace in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a couple of values in a text file: example

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9
```

I want to make a quartet, like:

```
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
9
```

How can I make it with the find/replace tool and `regex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record a macro:

```
step 1) keep your curson before 1,
step 2) click macro -> start recording
step 3) click end + click delete in sequence 4 times
step 4) click home button and down button
step 5) click macro -> stop recording
step 6) click ctrl + shift + p (run macro)
```

Once you learn to use macro, you will probably use it in Notepad++ for the rest of your life.

Do `step 6` to all the lines where you need to repeat `step 3` via a macro.

**Note 1**: This method expects you to do this manually once atleast so that the macro understands what to do automatically when you click ctrl + shift + p.

**Note 2**: You might observe that to do `step 3` itself we could write a macro by doing it once and running macro to do it 3 more times.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me in the "World of Macros" in Notepad++!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `(\d+),[\r\n]+(\d+),[\r\n]+(\d+),[\r\n]+(\d+),` by `$1,$2,$3,$4,`.

Don't forget to tick the regex checkbox.